# How to use 'throw new CustomError("error_message") inside a callback function ? NodeJS/ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, try-catch, throw

How can we throw error from a callback in NodeJS/ES6?
Throwing error synchronously works just fine -

Eg -

```
if (!email) {
      throw new CustomError("email_missing");
}
```

But 'throw' gives error when used inside a callback function.
Eg -

```
api.getData((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new CustomError("api_error");
  } else {
    callback(err, data);
  }
});
```

The console shows the following error -

```
server running on port 8080

D:\repo\generator\requestBot.js:50
  throw new CustomError("api_error");
  ^
  [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your custom error as the first argument for your callback.

```js
api.getData((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    callback(new CustomError("api_error"), null);
  } else {
    callback(err, data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ccristi for your reply. I was looking for the reason why does it fail and how can it be fixed at that very place only.
What I think the reason behind why it fails is that 'this' variable is different inside and outside a callback.